# Is there a proved performance and memory usage benchmark on the SWT & Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, swt, benchmarking

I want to know about SWT & Swing , memory usage and performance. which one has better performance and which one consumes less memory.

Is there a proved benchmark on these measures or everybody with good experience in these fields.

thanks

Comment: @Saeed Zarinfam: I can't answer your question but I can point out that in quite some cases Swing's memory consumption (which can be really terribly huge) can be fixed by following simple steps. For example I had one JTable that was bringing Swing to its knees and after following the Sun tutorial here: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/ everything was fine and smooth. So I don't know what you could compare, because I presume that SWT can *also* be optimized as to be "less worse".

Comment: @Saeed Zarinfam: Like @WizardOfOdds, I can't point to anything objective. Still, you can get a useful subjective comparison by downloading a premier example of each: Eclipse and NetBeans. Try a few examples or a familiar project. Alos, search SO for [java] [swing] [swt] to see a few pros & cons.

Comment: http://www.spec.org/benchmarks.html